# Drop down Links

Tags: html, dropdown, responsive

In the header of my website I have my regular menu, a search bar, and I want to add a drop down list with links to other websites. Can you give me some hints about the drop down list? I want it to be responsive so in bigger dimension screens it looks like |Links to other websites ->|  and in smaller screens it looks like | -> |
Can you give me some hints for this please?

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure of a drop down menu can be something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href="/company.htm">Company</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="/history.htm">History</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

You just have to hide the sub-menu with css and show it when you hover the parent `<li>` tag

Something like this:

```
.sub-menu{
   display: none;
}

#menu > li:hover > .sub-menu{
   display: block;
}
```

This are really the basics. Other styling rules are all up to you! Have fun.

About the responsive menu that you want, you should probably rely on javascript or maybe, if your website has only one language, try something with the pseudo-element :after, give it a content an change it with mediaqueries